# Ace syntax coloring is not working

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I can't get Ace syntax highlighter to work on my website.

HTML:

```
<textarea name="" id="upEditor" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="monokai.css">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
<script src='jquery.js'></script>
<script src='ace.js'></script>
<script src='script.js'></script>
```

JS:

```
var editor = ace.edit("upEditor");
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
```

I have both `mode-javascript.js` and `theme-monoki.js && monokai.css` in the same directory.
the text editor do have font size and family as the correct example editor but there's no highlight.

please help -thanks

Comment: What does the console show? any bugs poping? Do you have an element on the page with "upEditor" id? is the ace script included before the init script here?

Comment: also include more of the page code, maybe the problem is somewhere else

Comment: if the answer solves your question/problem with accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you aren't including the css links in the right place, so you don't get the css..

1. The css should be loaded in `<head>` and before `</head>`. while the textarea should be in the `<body>` section but above the scripts (should be last in body, but in this order.
2. Also I'm **not** sure the css `monokai.css` file is in the right place. you are calling it (and `normalize.css` and `style.css` from the same folder you have `index.html` but if as you mention in the question `monokai.css` is in the same folder as `theme-monokai.js` then the `href` should be `ace/theme/monokai.css`. check the other css files as well.
3. You should add `type="text/javascript"` to the script tag. older browsers may need this

Answer (score 0):

Ace doesn't work with textarea, use pre tag instead